# PHP Array Calculation

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [pid] => 877
    [encounter] => 15342
    [fee] => 300.00
)
Array
(
    [pid] => 877
    [encounter] => 15342
    [fee] => 300.00
)
Array
(
    [pid] => 1422
    [encounter] => 15332
    [fee] => 600.00
)
Array
(
    [pid] => 690
    [encounter] => 15335
    [fee] => 0.00
)
Array
(
    [pid] => 690
    [encounter] => 15335
    [fee] => 276.30
)
Array
(
    [pid] => 690
    [encounter] => 15335
    [fee] => 0.00
)
Array
(
    [pid] => 690
    [encounter] => 15335
    [fee] => 0.00
)
Array
(
    [pid] => 690
    [encounter] => 15338
    [fee] => 400.00
)
```

Code

```
$test_cnt = 0; 
test_encounter_pid = array(); 
foreach($provInnrArr as $dataDispArr){ 
    $test_encounter_pid['pid'] = $dataDispArr['pid']; 
    $test_encounter_pid['encounter'] = $dataDispArr['encounter']; 
    $test_encounter_pid['fee'] = $dataDispArr['fee']; 
    if (in_array($dataDispArr["encounter"], $test_encounter_pid)) { 
        $test_cnt += $dataDispArr['fee']; 
    } 
}
```

Hello Friends, Above is my array I am trying Sum all array fee key related values only when pid and encounter is different
I am getting 1,876.30 Total But Actual My need is 1,576.30
Because 300 extra adding of 2nd array value. I am not getting how to resolve it.

Comment: Make a foreach loop and check if the PID is same or not, if yes then add then fees to a new variable and finally echo the variable.

Comment: `array_sum(array_column(array_unique($array,SORT_REGULAR ),"fee")))`?

Comment: Show us HOW YOU ARE DOING the calculation

Comment: If the `pid` and `encounter` values are the same, which of the fees do you take?

Comment: $test_cnt = 0;
test_encounter_pid = array();
foreach($provInnrArr as $dataDispArr){          
 $test_encounter_pid['pid'] = $dataDispArr['pid'];
 $test_encounter_pid['encounter'] = $dataDispArr['encounter'];
 $test_encounter_pid['fee'] = $dataDispArr['fee'];
 if (in_array($dataDispArr["encounter"], $test_encounter_pid)) {
     $test_cnt += $dataDispArr['fee'];
 }
}

Comment: If the pid and encounter values are the same then take fee only once don't add in sum

Comment: What if there are two different values for `fee`, such as `100` and `200`? Or is it the case they are either a single value or `0`?

Comment: Array
(
    [pid] => 877
    [encounter] => 15342
    [fee] => 300.00
)

Array
(
    [pid] => 877
    [encounter] => 15342
    [fee] => 300.00
)

Array
(
    [pid] => 1422
    [encounter] => 15332
    [fee] => 600.00
)
Total Fee = 900 This is my case sir no possibility will be there

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
foreach($array as $val){

if($val['pid'] != "0"){
  if (!in_array($val['pid'], $temp_array))
  {
     $temp_array[] = $val['pid'];
     $total += $val['fee'];
  }
}

echo $total;
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/0X8AN)**

Comment: Hello Sir If same pid,encounter come in next case then it wont add that value

Comment: A bit simplistic @Dave what about the requirement to _Sum all array fee key related values **only when** pid and encounter is different_